# Two content area scrollable by browser's vertical and horizontal scrollbars

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to design page like on this picture:
[image: Two area scrollable by browser's scrollbar]

I need reach only three goals:

1. First content can be scrolled only vertically.
2. Second content can be scrolled only horizontally.
3. Must be used only browsers scrollbars.

p.s. Better if we will not use javascript code.

Comment: What have you tried? We aint making your homework, if you are asking that...

Comment: I tried somthing like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6r4y5/ - single vertical content with horizontal line with hidden inner scrollbar (user Shift+MouseWheel to scroll it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

The real difficulty is to add scrollbars outside de views. 
But when done, you can easily scroll to a position your scrollviews.

I don't think this is really a good feature to make this but why not.

Be strong!